# How to check whether entry in one row appears in another row but order of column values changed?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have some dataframe with Firs Name and Last Name columns, how can I check whether below case exist in dataframe and therefore extract all of the such cases:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| Albert | Einstein |
| Einstein | Albert |

?

In short, how can I check whether the criss cross cases exist in dataframe? The task at hand that I am trying to tackle is to locate all of the duplicates in terms of names in a dataframe. I am consider other cases (below), but they can be tackled separately.

- Different last names, same first name
- Same last name, different first name
- Same last name, same first name

Thanks!

Comment: Make a duplicate dataframe with the two columns reversed, then look for identical rows between the dataframes?

Comment: I mean, this works. However, is there a more efficient way? Also, how do I got about a case where I also have a Middle Name column which contributes to the similar case above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ordered tuple of your columns:

```
data = {'First Name': ['John', 'John', 'Kennedy'],
        'Middle Name': ['Fitzgerald', 'Kennedy', 'John'],
        'Last Name': ['Kennedy', 'Fitzgerald', 'Fitzgerald']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['key'] = df.apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), axis=1)
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
  First Name Middle Name   Last Name                          key
0       John  Fitzgerald     Kennedy  (Fitzgerald, John, Kennedy)
1       John     Kennedy  Fitzgerald  (Fitzgerald, John, Kennedy)
2    Kennedy        John  Fitzgerald  (Fitzgerald, John, Kennedy)
```

Now you have a key to use `duplicated` or `drop_duplicates` or whatever you want.

Comment: This actually makes sense. Ok, next question, how do I go about more anomalous entries (e.g., below):

First Name      | Last Name   ......... ...........................................................              
                                                                                                                   

James Agnew | Bond .........................................................................................................................................          

James             | Bond ...............................................................
?

Comment: This is an another (big) question because in this case you need fuzzy logic to determine similar names. It's not so simple. If you open a new question for that, don't forget to let me know here. FIY, you can use `thefuzz` package or `difflib` from standard library.

Comment: Hello Corralien,

As advised, please see below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483705/how-to-determine-if-two-rows-are-identical-similar-if-row-2-contains-part-of-t

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Doing the `np.sort` and check them with `duplicated`

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1[:] = np.sort(df1.values,1)
df1.duplicated(keep=False)
Out[144]: 
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```