# How to determine if two rows are identical (similar) if row 2 contains part of the info from row 1?

Tags: python, pandas

Hope you are having a good day. I am currently working with an extremely dirty dataframe containing First Name, Last Name, and Middle Name. One the issues that I am trying to resolve looks like below:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| James Agnew | Bond |
| James | Bond |

Another similar issue that I am trying to resolve looks like follows:

| First Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- |
| Jam | Bond |
| James | Bond |

Looking forward to your ideas.

Thanks!

Edit: FYI, to make life simpler, I already have data grouped by address which is unique. So, two rows will have one address, another two or three rows will have another address, and so on.

Comment: Use `df.drop_duplicates('Address')` to keep only one instance of (First Name, Last Name)?

Comment: Not that easy. I have other rows with a similar issue (please see my other post). I could drop rows which are pure duplicates and then drop rows which are criss cross duplicates.

Comment: I tried to find a solution but it takes too many time because you need to check NxN combinations. Sorry :(

Answer (score -1):

This is a not so simple problem. To check if 2 strings are 'similar' you must enter in non-Euclidean distance algorithm.
I mean, you must define a similarity function and 'understand' the distance between string.

[jellyfish](https://pypi.org/project/jellyfish/) is a library born to solve these problems

Another approach is to collect all names and bind them to a thesaurus of names like [this](https://www.caagri.org/nicknames.html)

With a some search,  I've found [this](https://github.com/carltonnorthern/nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup)

hope can help

Answer (score -1):

If we just want to check that both elements in row2 are contained in the respective elements of row1, we just need one if statement

```
row1 = ["James", "Bond"]
row2 = ["Jam", "Bo"]

if row2[0] in row1[0] and row2[1] in row1[1]:   
    print("Similar!")
else:
    print("Not Similar!")
```

If you want to check the opposite case (that ro1 is in row2), just create a second if statement with 'row1' and 'row2' terms swapped.

Comment: What if we want to check for similar cases throughout the whole dataframe?

Comment: @IsaacA You'd have to compare each row against every other row. A nested for loop going over every possible 2-row combination would work.